# Ionic Framework: Left and Right sidemenus disappear on navigation

Tags: menu, navigation, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create an ionic app which has a left and right sidemenu, but I'm finding that the side-menu icons (and the ability to swipe left or right to open them) is disappearing when I try to navigate. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't see what it is.

see here ... http://plnkr.co/NpqmVT ... for plunker which demonstrates the problem. To replicate the bug simply click on the 'click to view details' button.

My main user interface (I'm guessing this is where I'm doing something wrong) looks like this...

```
            <ion-side-menu-content>
                    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">

                            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                                    </button>
                            </ion-nav-buttons>

                            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
                                    </button>

                            </ion-nav-buttons>
                    </ion-nav-bar>

                    <ion-nav-view name="centre-panel"></ion-nav-view>

            </ion-side-menu-content> 

            <ion-side-menu side="left">
                    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                            <h1 class="title">Main Menu</h1>
                    </ion-header-bar>
                    <ion-content>
                            <ion-list>
                                    <ion-item ui-sref="ui.page1" nav-clear menu-close >Page 1</ion-item>
                                    <ion-item ui-sref="ui.page2" nav-clear menu-close >Page 2</ion-item>
                            </ion-list>
                    </ion-content>
            </ion-side-menu>

            <ion-side-menu side="right">
                    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                            <h1 class="title">Right Menu</h1>
                    </ion-header-bar>
                    <ion-nav-view name="right-panel"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-side-menu>

    </ion-side-menus>
```

All the routes, etc can be found in the plunkr (http://plnkr.co/NpqmVT)

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 5):

just faced the same problem and found a solution - add this directive to the ion-side menus:
`<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">`